# How to remove characters in String Swift 3?

Tags: swift, string

Code to get the string before a certain character:

```
let string = "Hello World"
if let range = string.range(of: "World") {
    let firstPart = string[string.startIndex..<range.lowerBound]
    print(firstPart) // print Hello
}
```

To begin with, I have a program that converts Hex float to a Binary float and I want to remove all "0" from Binary string answer until first "1". Example:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string

Comment: Here is a way of converting that won't create the leading 0's in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36967037/1630618 . In your case `String(Int("3b9", radix: 16)!, radix: 2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression:

```
var str = "001110111001"
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "0", with: "", options: [.anchored], range: nil)
```

The `anchored` option means search for `0`s at the start of the string only.

Comment: Also possible with `"^0+"` and `.regularExpression`.